# Weak convergence in intersection of Bochner spaces

Tags: reference-request, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, interpolation-theory

First off, my question has some similarities to [Weak convergence in the intersection of Lebesgue spaces or Sobolev spaces (on MathOverflow)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135125/weak-convergence-in-the-intersection-of-lebesgue-spaces-or-sobolev-spaces).

To be specific, we have a Gelfand triple $V \subset H \subset V^*$ and a complete probability space $([0,T]\times\Omega,\mathcal{B}([0,T])\otimes\mathcal{F},\text{Lebesgue}\otimes\mathbb{P})$. Then, we have the Bochner spaces $L^{\alpha}([0,T]\times\Omega;V)$ (where $\alpha>1$) and $L^2([0,T]\times\Omega;H)$. Let $p:=\min\{\alpha,2\}>1$. Then, both of these spaces can be continuously and linearly embedded into the reflexive space $L^p([0,T]\times\Omega;H)$, and so, $K:=L^{\alpha}([0,T]\times\Omega;V)\cap L^2([0,T]\times\Omega;H)$ is a Banach space, when endow with the norm 
$$
\|f\|_{K}:=\max\left\{\|f\|_{L^{\alpha}([0,T]\times\Omega;V)},\|f\|_{L^{2}([0,T]\times\Omega;Hil)}\right\}
$$
for all $f\in K$. I would like to verify that the following statement holds.

> We consider a bounded sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset K$ and we want to finish by concluding that, by possibly taking some subsequence, we have 
>   $f_n \overset{\text{wk}}{\to}f$ in $L^{\alpha}([0,T]\times\Omega;V)$ and $f_n \overset{\text{wk}}{\to}f$ in $L^2([0,T]\times\Omega;H)$ for some $f\in K$. To emphasize: the $f$ is the same in both cases.

At first, I showed that weak convergence in $K$ implies weak convergence to both respective spaces and thought I was done, since $(f_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $K$. Later, I realized that it might be possible that $K$ is not reflexive, so the boundedness of the sequence in $K$ does not directly imply weak convergence.

Then, I recalled that closed subspaces of reflexive spaces are reflexive as well, but $K$ is endowed with a different norm, so that statement does not apply.

I searched online for some results, and I found a paper by Liu and Wang, *Sums and Intersection of Lebesgue Spaces*, in which it is showed that the intersection of Lebesgue-spaces $L^{p}$ and $L^{q}$ (where $p,q>1$) is indeed reflexive (Corollary 2 on page 245), so I am inclined to believe such a statement can hold in this setting as well.

However, the reflexivity is not necessary, I just want to verify that such a result holds. I believe it might be possible with interpolation theory, but I am not really familiar in that branch of mathematics.

---

**[ADDED]** I have yet another unfruitful attempt to show this result. I tried combining [Reflexivity of intersection of two $L^p$ space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493550/reflexivity-of-intersection-of-two-lp-space) with [Uniform convexity of equivalent intersection norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063658/uniform-convexity-of-equivalent-intersection-norm/1067743), which would have given a positive answer, *if* the Banach space $V$ would have been uniformly convex, which is not assumed. Namely, if that were the case, Theorem 2 in M. M. Day's *Some more uniformly convex spaces* would yield that $L^{\alpha}([0,T]\times\Omega;V)$ is indeed uniformly convex and we could apply [Uniform convexity of equivalent intersection norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063658/uniform-convexity-of-equivalent-intersection-norm/1067743) and rest our heads.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is based on [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1493687/221789) in the linked question [Reflexivity of intersection of two $L^p$ space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493550/reflexivity-of-intersection-of-two-lp-space).

---

Define $p:=\min\{\alpha,2\}$. We can continuously and linearly embed the Banach spaces $L^{\alpha}([0,T]\times\Omega;V)$ and $L^{2}([0,T]\times\Omega;H)$ in the Banach space $L^{p}([0,T]\times\Omega;H)$. Hence, the intersection $K := L^{\alpha}([0,T]\times\Omega;V)\cap L^{2}([0,T]\times\Omega;H)$ is a Banach space as well, when endowed with the norm
$$
\left\|\Xi\right\|_{K} := \max\left\{\left\|\Xi\right\|_{L^{\alpha}([0,T]\times\Omega;V)}, \left\|\Xi\right\|_{L^{2}([0,T]\times\Omega;H)}\right\}
$$
for any $\Xi \in K$.

Moreover, the Banach spaces $L^{\alpha}([0,T]\times\Omega;V)$ and $L^{2}([0,T]\times\Omega;H)$ are reflexive. This means that the product space $\mathcal{P} := L^{\alpha}([0,T]\times\Omega;V)\times L^{2}([0,T]\times\Omega;H)$, endowed with the norm 
$$
\|(\phi,\psi)\|_{\mathcal{P}} := \max\left\{\|\phi\|_{L^{\alpha}([0,T]\times\Omega;V)},\|\psi\|_{L^{2}([0,T]\times\Omega;H)}\right\}
$$
[is a reflexive Banach space as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831791/cartesian-product-of-reflexive-spaces-is-reflexive). If we look at the "diagonal" of this product space $\mathcal{D} := \{(\phi,\psi)\in \mathcal{P} : \phi = \psi\}$, it immediately follows that this linear subspace of the product space is closed. As a consequence, we see that $\left(\mathcal{D}, \|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{P}}\right)$ is a reflexive Banach space.

Consider the bounded linear operator $\kappa: K \to\mathcal{P} : \Xi \mapsto (\Xi,\Xi)$. Then, we see that the image of $\kappa$ is equal to the diagonal $\mathcal{D}$ of the product space $\mathcal{P}$ and moreover, we find that $K$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are isometrically isomorphic. This means that $K$ is reflexive.

In particular, this means that the bounded sequence $\{f_n:n\geq1\}\subset K$ has a weakly convergent subsequence that we will again denote by $\{f_n:n\geq1\}$. Then, as "weak convergence in K implies weak convergence to both respective spaces" (by restricting the functionals, which are again functionals , but now on $K$), we are done.